# Can the US not process more than some maximum of unemployment claims?

Tags: discussion

What 'details or clarity'  are needed for [Can the US not process more than some maximum of unemployment claims?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/can-the-us-not-process-more-than-some-maximum-of-unemployment-claims?noredirect=1#comment217614_47359)

> This question needs [details or clarity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.

Comment: Three random posters on the internet claiming there is some fixed limit and implying that it is deliberate to avoid paying benefits, against the reality that everything is limited in some way, especially bureaucracy and especially processing systems, what exactly is the claim here meant to be?

Comment: @Is there "some fixed limit" that "is deliberate to avoid paying benefits"?

Answer (score 4):

The question is rather unclear - I strongly suspect you have some differing implicit assumptions to me (and other readers) which is causing a blockage in understanding.

For example, as it stands now, the question could be answered:

> Yes. The US cannot process more than 10^82 unemployment claims per day. There aren't enough atoms in the universe to document each claim.

That's obviously facetious, but the fact that it is a legitimate answer suggests that the question needs clarifying.

In practice, it is a complex system. We would *expect* that each day it would have some maximum capacity. It seems likely that the capacity might vary based on the availability of various limited resources, including staff, and by the complexity of the applications, how long people are willing to queue, network speeds and dozens of other varying factors. So asking "what exactly is the maximum number of unemployment claims?" is making a whole lot of unjustified assumptions.

The fact that one random guy on the internet going by the name "fucks_with_his_dog" thinks it looks like it might be deliberate does not make that a notable claim, and it is a totally different claim to "There is an artificial limit of (say) 2,097,152 applicants per day imposed by law/regulation/software".

Jumping from there to *motivation* would make it out of scope.